# Where do Django logs get logged to?

Tags: python, django, debugging, exception, logging

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#topic-logging-parts-loggers

I'm reading this doc.

What happens when you log something? Where does it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are saved to:

```
/var/www/django/log
```